# grep a specific value when the matching criteria happens twice in the line

Tags: python, regex, shell, awk, grep

There are two lengths in the following line. I want to extract the value 46 and add 16 to it.

```
1466352405.455975 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 46) 192.168.52.53.32769 > 192.168.52.54.9600: UDP, length 18
```

I tried grep `'\slength' | cut -d: -f1` but it doesn't give the correct result. I expect to obtain 46 and add 16 to it. So final value should be 64.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '{print $17+16}' file
62
```

If that's not what you wanted then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean "add 18 to it" ;)

Anyway, since you tagged your question with "python"

```
import re
s = "1466352405.455975 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 46) 192.168.52.53.32769 > 192.168.52.54.9600: UDP, length 18"
re.findall("length (\d+)",s)
```

Comment: well print(sum([int(x) for x in re.findall("length (\d+)",s)]) :P

Answer (score 0):

Use the following snippet in `Python`:

```
import re

regex = r'length (\d+)'
# search for length, a space and digits (capture these)
string = "1466352405.455975 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 46) 192.168.52.53.32769 > 192.168.52.54.9600: UDP, length 18"

numbers = re.findall(regex, string)
print numbers
# ['46', '18']
```

And see [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/uvKRxD).
To `sum()` it up, you could tweak the code to:

```
# taken from http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Recursion/pythondsCalculatingtheSumofaListofNumbers.html
def listsum(numList):
    theSum = 0
    for i in numList:
        theSum = theSum + int(i)
    return theSum

print listsum(numbers)
# 64
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the rules of the input format, it's impossible to give you a good answer.  Given what you showed us,

```
awk '{ x = 16 + $17; print x }'
```

will print 62.  If you want it to print 64, add 18 instead.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you split the input on `length` in Awk, the first numeric token in each field can be accessed as if it was tne entire field in arithmetic operations.

```
awk -F length 'NF==3{ print $2+16 }'
```

As you would expect, the second value is available in `$3` if you should want that.

If you want to do this unconditionally, remove the condition `NF==3` which currently verifies that there are two occurrences of `length` (you might want `NF>3` to check for two or more).  If there are no occurrences, splitting will not split, so the number of fields will be one (the entire line); if there is only one occurrence, the line will be split on that, so there are two input fields -- the part from before the occurrence, and the part from after; etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command to get the second length:

`grep -oP 'length \d+.+length \d+' | grep -oP '\d+$'`

For the given sample, it obtains 18 correctly, adding 16 to the result is not a problem for you.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to add 46 and 18.

For a single line you can use following command

```
grep -o "length [0-9]*" file | cut -d " " -f2 | xargs | awk '{print $1 + $2}'
```

On execution with your example it gives the result 64.

Please note that you will have to use it in loop if there are multiple lines in the file.

Cheers!

Comment: That's insanely complex for a task which can easily be solved in Awk alone.

Comment: @tripleee This solution is suggested assuming the user has to add both the numbers (46 and 18) preceded by **length**. As there is no well defined rule for input, I believe we cannot use awk here. Your solution adds a constant 18.